# Fastest way to scale an SKImage (SkiaSharp)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, skiasharp

I'm looking for the fastest way to resize an SKImage. Unfortunately I found a few examples.

I ask this because if I perform these functions in parallel (in my case about 60 threads) the execution time of each single scaling function increases up to twenty times as much.

I tried with the following methods and the performance looks very similar, is there anything better?

Method 1:

```
SKImage src = (...);
SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo(width, height, SKColorType.Bgra8888);
SKImage output = SKImage.Create(info);
src.ScalePixels(output.PeekPixels(), SKFilterQuality.None);
```

Method 2:

```
SKImage src = (...);
SKImage output;
float resizeFactorX = (float)width / (float)Src.Width;
float resizeFactorY = (float)height / (float)Src.Height;

using (SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create((int)(Src.Width * 
       resizeFactorX), (int)(Src.Height * resizeFactorY),
       SKColorType.Bgra8888, SKAlphaType.Opaque))
{
  surface.Canvas.SetMatrix(SKMatrix.MakeScale(resizeFactorX, resizeFactorY));
  surface.Canvas.DrawImage(Src, 0, 0);
  surface.Canvas.Flush();
  output = surface.Snapshot();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I use. An additional thought is to be sure to wrap your SKImage objects in `using`, to ensure they're disposed of quickly. I'm not sure if that could be causing the slowdown with each iteration.

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(resizedWidth, resizedHeight,
    SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul))
using (var paint = new SKPaint())
{
    // high quality with antialiasing
    paint.IsAntialias = true;
    paint.FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High;

    // draw the bitmap to fill the surface
    surface.Canvas.DrawImage(srcImg, new SKRectI(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight),
        paint);
    surface.Canvas.Flush();

    using (var newImg = surface.Snapshot())
    {
        // do something with newImg
    }
}
```

Comment: The SKSurface.Create overload obsolete and will generate a warning. The modern code is `SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo { Width = resizedWidth, Height = resizedHeight, ColorType = SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, AlphaType = SKAlphaType.Premul })`

Comment: I tested this vs the current SKBitMap.Resize and it seems now that they produce identical results so no need for the Canvas anymore or most of this code